# Using an address as a parameter in assembly

Tags: assembly, procedure, masm, masm32

I'm writing a procedure with two parameters, one is a number and the other is an address to an array. How can I write the prototype for this? 
I was trying:

```
Print proto dword: Asz, Addr Arrayn
```

as well as:

```
 Print proto dword: Asz, OFFSET Arrayn
```

but neither of these are working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Print proto Asz:dword, Arrayn:ptr byte
```

or if near is needed

```
Print proto Asz:dword, Arrayn:near ptr byte
```

The procedure (proc) will need the same parameter types.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the reply! Can you guide me on how I call invoke on it? I have now used the prototype: 
Print proto Asz:dword, Arrayn:ptr byte

When calling the function I use:
invoke Print number, ArrayX
(With Arrayx and number being declared respectably)
The way I am calling is incorrect for sure and I receive the error :
error A2206: missing operator in expression

Comment: @GoogleZ - you may need to use "offset ArrayX" for the second parameter.